# JSF multiple kinds of objects in a datatable

Tags: list, jsf, datatable

I wanna know how can i put in a datatable multiple kinds of objects. I have stored in a database objects of many types. I have to show them in a datatable.

Can anybody tell me how can i do it?

att,

Diego Sabino

Comment: What have you tried? Please post some code otherwise this would be too broad to answer.

Comment: I've not tried anything. This is exactly my question, i have no ideia how can i do it.  the datatable in JSF has in your value some Collection of some type of object. In the managedBean i have, for example, some List<Type> listOfObject. But what can i do if i have multiple types of objects?

Comment: Use different `List<TypeA>`, `List<TypeB>` , `List<TypeC>` and on...? IMO this could be a lot of job but it is way better than having a single `GodEntity` that contains a `Map<String, String>` with the different fields and values for maintenance purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar situation, I thought of two options.

1. Adapter/Wrapper object for all different objects, and use wrapper methods to show data.
2. Let objects implement an interface and use that interface methods to pull relevant information for datatable.

Hope this helps.